# Dynamically Resize div using mouse

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize

I want to have a div tag with resize capability using mouse. I mean when I mousedown on any of the corner of the div and drag the mouse then the div should be resized according to the mouse movement. And when I leave the mouse button the div should have this size permanently.
Thank You

Answer (score 11):

jQuery UI Resizable does just that for you.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/

```
$(function() {
    $( "#resizable" ).resizable();
});
```

Comment: This is to be done without jQuery

Comment: @AmitSharma - Nothing in your question states that this should be done without jquery so I don't think you are in the right position to downvote anyone.